# I Want to search Specific item from another datagridview to another datagridview and get the sum of the value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow

want to search items using datagridview 1 as my search Engine and search to datagridview2 and display the result to datagridview2

it must go like this

[Datagridview1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNv9v.png)

[datagridview2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWdMz.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and does the DataGridView have a DataSource and what type of project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `DataTable` defined (you should, if you want to work with grid data), you can define and use following method:

C#:

```
public void SumValues(ref DataTable DataTable1, Int32 ColIdx, string SearchStr)
{
    Int32 RetSum;   // change datatype, if needed
    foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
    {
        if (!IsDBNull(row(0)) && !IsNothing(row(ColIdx)) && row(ColIdx) == SearchStr && !IsDBNull(row(ColIdx)) && !IsNothing(row(ColIdx)))
            RetSum += row(ColIdx);// add a value from column with index ColIdx, if value of the first column is SearchStr
    }
    return RetSum;
}
```

To get sum of som column for particular search string:

```
var colSum = SumValues(dt1, 5, "Ref 5");
```

To place the sum into the 2nd table:

```
DataTable2("SumOfValues")(5) = colSum;
```

You can work with `DataGridView` values directly:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(iRow).Cells("SumOfValues").Value = ColSum;
```

...but I wouldn't recommend it. You can get into trouble with DataTypes and more.

---

VB.NET:

```
Public Function SumValues(ByRef DataTable1 As DataTable, ColIdx As Int32, SearchStr As String)
    Dim RetSum As Int32   ' change datatype, if needed
    For Each row As DataRow In DataTable1.Rows
        If Not IsDBNull(row(0)) AndAlso Not IsNothing(row(ColIdx)) AndAlso row(ColIdx) = SearchStr AndAlso Not IsDBNull(row(ColIdx)) AndAlso Not IsNothing(row(ColIdx)) Then
            RetSum += row(ColIdx)  ' add a value from column with index ColIdx, if value of the first column is SearchStr
        End If
    Next
    Return RetSum
End Function

Dim colSum = SumValues(dt1, 5, "Ref 5")

DataTable2("SumOfValues")(5) = colSum
```